# Quem oferece uma recompensa, pode recebê-la?

Tags: debate, recompensa

Sempre tive essa curiosidade, apesar de já saber que a resposta seria um **não** bem grandão :D

Se uma pergunta é feita e seja qual for o motivo ela mereça/precise uma recompensa, o que acontece com a reputação ofertada caso a melhor resposta, inclusive se marcada como aceita, vier da própria pessoa que ofereceu a recompensa?

Não seria o caso de a recompensa ser removida e a reputação devolvida a quem ofereceu?

Comment: Marquei como duplicata por considerar que todas essas dúvidas estão respondidas na outra pergunta. Se faltar algo, me avise.

Comment: Sim e não. Na outra resposta é dito que a recompensação automática com metade do ofertado se dá à primeira resposta postada com 2 ou mais *upvotes*. Mas não fica claro quanto a outra metade. O sistema engole eles e beleza?

Comment: Engole. Porque a lógica é que você paga pra promover a pergunta, não é exatamente uma recompensa apesar do nome.

Comment: http://nooooooooooooooo.com/vader.jpg

Answer (score 5):

## Não

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: (esse é o maior tamanho de fonte que o site permite)

Comment: Ah, a ironia... :P