# O que acontece quando uma recompensa expira?

Tags: debate, suporte, duvida

Eu li https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty no entanto tive uma dúvida, já que não esclarece o que acontece quando uma pergunta expira.

Eu ofereci 100 de reputação como recompensa nesta pergunta [Como ter duas versões do php no mesmo servidor Apache?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334553/como-ter-duas-vers%C3%B5es-do-php-no-mesmo-servidor-apache) , no entanto, só houve a minha resposta.

Partindo da ideia de [Quem oferece uma recompensa, pode recebê-la?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2352/quem-oferece-uma-recompensa-pode-receb%C3%AA-la) , em que eu não posso ganhar a minha própria recompensa, o que acontece com a reputação que eu ofereci como recompensa? Perde-se?

Comment: Como já explicado no link do fechamento acima, você não "perde", você "investiu na divulgação da postagem" (tendo ela atingido sua intenção ou não, o destaque ocorreu). Mais detalhes na postagem linkada acima, em especial as seguintes partes: *"Considera-se como "publicidade" e a reputação não é reembolsável"* e *"Tem vezes que o motivo era obter uma resposta e isso não acontece, mas, reiterando, a pessoa não "paga" por uma resposta, "paga" pelo destaque."*

Comment: É o que o @Bacco falou. E de forma bem rude e resumida do processo é o seguinte, ela vai para a resposta que solucionou a dúvida do usuário, caso nenhuma solucione, vai para a mais votada e em último caso vai para ninguém.